# Compare int variable after assign in php

Tags: php

I have a simple php code :

```
<?php
$page = 2;
$max = $page * 10 + 1;
$min = $page - 11;
$counter = 1;

if($counter > $min && $counter < $max) // so, it will be if(1 > 9 && 1 < 20)
{
    echo "true!";
}
else
{
    echo "false!";
}
?>
```

If I run this code, It always echo true. However, If I change the assign like this :

```
$max = 21;
$min = 9;
```

The code work fine and echo false. Where did I wrong?

Edit : The code work fine if value of counter >= 9 :(

P/S : sorry for bad English.

Comment: You have to change your $counter to get a false response. Your $min is -9 and your $max is 21. So any value of $counter from -8 to 20 will return true, otherwise false. But with that kind of static values your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$page = 2;
$min = $page - 11;
```

That means `$min` is `-9`, not `9`.

Comment: Ah, I see it. My bad :D

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the line:

```
$min = $page - 11;
```

sets `$min` to -9, not 9 (because `$page` is 2).

Therefore, `$counter > $min && $counter < $max` would be true, because `1 > -9 AND 1 < 21`.

Comment: Ah, I see it. My bad :D